# Measuring the toss value

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, probability

Simply, can we calculate the value of tossing a coin, either heads or tails, before it falls down.
Can you explain how we will need height of coin above the ground, mass of coin (I don't know why), force of impact given to coin by the thumb etc.?

And do we have the enough computational power to perform it live before it falls down or before we choose our side (heads/tails)?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you explain how we will need height of coin above the ground, mass of coin (I don't know why), force of impact given to coin by the thumb etc.?

I will explain it point wise:

1. You will need mass to calculate everything which includes moment of inertia of coin max. height reached by the coin, etc.
2. You will need the force applied by your thumb to calculate the max. height reached by the coin and the distance of the point of application of force from the centre of coin to calculate the angular velocity of the coin which in turn will provide you which side hits the ground first (or rim of coin on which side hits the ground first).
   You can calculate the initial velocity given by the impulse by your thumb as $$v_i = \frac{p}{m} $$ where $v_i$ is the initial velocity, p is the change in momentum and m is the mass of the coin.
   After this you can calculate the max height reached by the coin using $$h_{\text{max}} =  \frac{0-v_i^2}{-2g}$$ and then you will calculate the angular velocity by $$\omega = \frac{pd}{I}$$ where $p$ is impulse, $d$ is distance of impulse from the centre and $I$ is the moment of inertia along length axis.
   With these two numbers you can calculate how many revolutions the coin has completed when it gets close to the ground, and then you would have to figure out when the coin first hits the surface - this is not when the center of mass hits h=0, but rather when a rim of the coin does - and that depends on the angular position and we assume that the coin sticks to the ground after hitting it otherwise you would need to take the properties of the surface in account.
   Now for the computational power:
   Yes ofcourse we have but there are many implications because this is very sensitive system it becomes chaotic i.e. any small change in the initial values will lead to huge change in the results.
   One model could be that you take a high speed camera mark a point on the rim of the coin which camera can identify toss the coin the camera will give the values and computer will calculate the no. of rotations and max height and then the result but as I said it is very sensitive system.
   Hope it helps. :)